# Shape error when predicting with a trained model in tensorflow.keras

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I'm creating a 1D CNN using `tensorflow.keras`, following [this tutorial](https://pythonprogramming.net/convolutional-neural-network-deep-learning-python-tensorflow-keras/), with some of the concepts from [this tutorial](https://machinelearningmastery.com/cnn-models-for-human-activity-recognition-time-series-classification/). So far modeling and training seem to be working, but I can't seem to generate a prediction. Here's an example of what I'm dealing with:

### Data

```
import numpy as np
from keras.utils import to_categorical

NUM_SAMPLES = 1000
NUM_TRACES = 6
SAMPLE_LENGTH = 512
trainX = np.random.rand(NUM_SAMPLES,SAMPLE_LENGTH,NUM_TRACES)
trainy = to_categorical(np.random.randint(2, size=NUM_SAMPLES))
```

In this example, I'm creating a dataset which represents what I'm working with. I have 1000 windows of time series data, each of which has 6 distinct traces (accelerometer x,y,z and gyro x,y,z). The lengths of these windows are 512 data points long.

### Training

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv1D, MaxPooling1D

verbose, epochs, batch_size = 1, 3, 32
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', input_shape = trainX[0].shape))
model.add(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(trainX, trainy, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=verbose)
```

Creating a simple CNN, this trains perfectly with the following output:

```
Train on 1000 samples
Epoch 1/3
1000/1000 [==============================] - 1s 1ms/sample - loss: 0.8802 - accuracy: 0.4930
Epoch 2/3
1000/1000 [==============================] - 1s 724us/sample - loss: 0.6726 - accuracy: 0.5920
Epoch 3/3
1000/1000 [==============================] - 1s 740us/sample - loss: 0.6291 - accuracy: 0.6760
```

### Prediction (where the error comes up)

for testing purposes, I'm predicting a portion of training data. Running `model.predict(trainX[0])` results in the following error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv1d_4_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (512, 6)
```

this seems peculiar, as I would expect compatibility of the training dataset; after all, `trainX[0]` is what defined the `input_shape` in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please runing the code: `model.predict([trainX[0]])`, and the model outputs the predicted  results

Comment: Didn't work. Running `model.predict([trainX[0]])` resulted in the same error `Error when checking input: expected conv1d_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (510, 6)`

Comment: I've already run your code, please run the code: `model.predict(np.array([trainX[0]]))`

Comment: Yep, I ended up finding that out. Also `model.predict([[trainX[0]]])` seems to work, based on my recollection. Can you edit your answer?

Answer (score 0):

On my laptop `X_new = [[30, 74, 11, 31, 20]]`, `prediction = model.predict(X_new)`

I got the correct result.
On my desktop, I got an error about the shape being 1 and not 5. So I tried
`prediction = model.predict(np.array(X_new))` and it worked.
I am not sure why it worked on one machine and not on the other. Both have the same version of TensorFlow.